# Irrelevant ambigious method call error on intelliJ with spark sql

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

This spark sql code compiles and run but intelliJ (idea-IU-172.4343.14) shows an "Ambigious method call" error.

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession session = SparkSession //
            .builder() //
            .appName("idea-ambigious-method-call-bug") //
            .master("local[*]") //
            .getOrCreate();


    Dataset<String> cities = session//
            .sqlContext()//
            .createDataset(Arrays.asList("Paris", "Porto", "London"), Encoders.STRING());

    cities.filter(name -> name.startsWith("P")).show();
}
```

This wasn't happening with previous versions of intelliJ.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: If IntelliJ has behaviour that's discrepant compared to the javac compiler, report it as a bug to JetBrains : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: The behavior isn't really discrepant as in spark sql code the filter method is overloaded, there's a java specefic fitler and a scala specefic filter, untill the latest versions intelliJ managed to choose the right one.

Comment: Right, but if your project is set-up right, then either: 1. the Scala function should not be in your source file's namespace; or 2. this is an ambiguity that the Java compiler has rules for resolving. One way or the other it seems like a bug in how IDEA handles things, which I'm not sure is anything anyone here can solve. (Now, if the javac compiler was also complaining, that would be more likely to be a programmer error we can help with.)

Comment: You were right, it was an IntelliJ bug. Simply updating to idea-IU-173 (which is currently EAP) solved it for me.

Comment: The bug came back in next versions.

Comment: There is a method overloading in [filter function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#filter-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction-). If you want to use java-specific one in a lambda expression, you should explicitly define the interface. Sample usage: `data.filter((FilterFunction<String>)s -> s.contains("hello"))`

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be linked to the scala plugin. The plugin makes the source code of Spark readable and IntelliJ fails in choosing the right method. If you deinstall the plugin from IntelliJ everything should work fine. However, you'll loose the possibility to have a readable Spark source code.

Comment: You are right ! Except that I can't use this solution as in the same project I also have scala code.

Answer (score 2):

It runs fine when you remove Spark core dependency.

try same code with just below Spark sql dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same issue(Multiple implementation for map), on IntelliJ IU-182, but if run the same program from terminal, don't have any compiler issue.

```
    SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("ALB log Analyzer").master("local[2]").getOrCreate();
    Dataset<ALBLog> accessLogs = session.read().textFile(logFile).map(ALBLog::parseAlbLog,
            Encoders.bean(ALBLog.class));
```